# When is OCaml's warning 27 "Innocuous unused variable" useful?

Tags: ocaml

This is the description of warning 27 from the [OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html):

> 27 Innocuous unused variable: unused variable that is not bound with `let` nor `as`, and doesn't start with an underscore (`_`) character.

This warning is turned on by `jbuilder --dev`, and I'm curious to know in which cases people find it useful. For me, it's an annoyance to get warnings when I write code like this:

```
$ utop -w +27
utop # fun (x, y) -> x;;
Characters 8-9:
Warning 27: unused variable y.
- : 'a * 'b -> 'a = <fun>
```

or like that:

```
utop # let error loc msg = failwith (loc ^ ": " ^ msg);;
val error : string -> string -> 'a = <fun>
utop # let rec eval = function
| `Plus (loc, a, b) -> eval a + eval b
| `Minus (loc, a, b) -> eval a - eval b
| `Star (loc, a, b) -> eval a * eval b
| `Slash (loc, a, b) ->
    let denom = eval b in
    if denom = 0 then
      error loc "division by zero"
    else
      eval a / denom
| `Int (loc, x) -> x
;;
Characters 33-36:
Warning 27: unused variable loc.
Characters 73-76:
Warning 27: unused variable loc.
Characters 112-115:
Warning 27: unused variable loc.
Characters 287-290:
Warning 27: unused variable loc.
val eval :
  ([< `Int of 'b * int
    | `Minus of 'c * 'a * 'a
    | `Plus of 'd * 'a * 'a
    | `Slash of 'e * 'a * 'a
    | `Star of 'f * 'a * 'a ]
   as 'a) ->
  int = <fun>
```

I know that prepending an underscore to the identifiers as in `_loc` suppresses the warnings, but it's not compatible with my notions that:

1. variables starting with an underscore are ugly and are meant for use in generated code, hidden from the programmer;
2. a name given to something should not have to change based on how it's used (including unused).

Using underscores, the code becomes:

```
(* Here we have _loc or loc depending on whether it's used. *)
let rec eval = function
| `Plus (_loc, a, b) -> eval a + eval b
| `Minus (_loc, a, b) -> eval a - eval b
| `Star (_loc, a, b) -> eval a * eval b
| `Slash (loc, a, b) ->
    let denom = eval b in
    if denom = 0 then
      error loc "division by zero"
    else
      eval a / denom
| `Int (_loc, x) -> x
```

or

```
(* Here it can be hard to know what _ stands for. *)
let rec eval = function
| `Plus (_, a, b) -> eval a + eval b
| `Minus (_, a, b) -> eval a - eval b
| `Star (_, a, b) -> eval a * eval b
| `Slash (loc, a, b) ->
    let denom = eval b in
    if denom = 0 then
      error loc "division by zero"
    else
      eval a / denom
| `Int (_, x) -> x
```

Comment: I personally find it useful that unused bindings are differentiated from used ones. Specifically, when I read `Plus (_loc, a, b)`, I know that I don't need to pay attention to `_loc`. Depending on the scenario, `Plus (_, a, b)` can be even better; it clearly shows we only care about positional values `a` and `b` here; it doesn't matter what `_` is, it's discarded/unused in the body anyway

Comment: A warning is exactly that: a message that something *may* be wrong. If you define a variable somewhere and don't use it, it may indicate a typo or something, as in `let add a b = a + a`.

Comment: @user633183 FWIW the way I see this is (1) an unused variable doesn't cost an extra computation and (2) it just gives a name to yet another item in the environment and it tells me it's available if I want to use it. I read `_loc` as something auto-generated that I should probably not touch and I suppose not everyone reads it this way.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne of course we don't want warnings when everything is fine. Unlike @ivg I can't remember having a bug due to not using a variable introduced in a pattern (other than `let` or `as`). However I do remember reporting the wrong location in camlp4 code due to having code like `let f loc x = match x with Foo (_, y) -> error loc "..."` which should have been `let f loc x = match x with Foo (loc, y) -> error loc "..."`. ymmv

Comment: @MartinJambon: Which is the point of the underscore notation. To the developer or to the compiler, it tells "Don't worry about it, I know what I'm doing."

Comment: @Richard-Degenne I usually don't know what I'm doing. I want the compiler to work for me, not the other way around.

Answer (score 11):

It is very useful in the monadic code, where instead of the common syntactic `let` bindings you're forced to use monadic `>>=` bind operator. Basically, where

```
let x = something in
code
```

translates to

```
something >>= fun x ->
code
```

If `x` is not used in `code` then only with the 27 warning enabled the latter will be highlighted, while the former will produce a warning by default. Enabling this warning, revealed lots of bugs for us. For example, it showed us that [this code](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/ce4bd1e25fa0685f4db433c0ab6bc0a4ad86bdba/plugins/primus_mark_visited/primus_mark_visited_main.ml#L33) is buggy :)

Another source of use cases are higher-order functions, i.e., `map`, `fold`, etc. It captures one of the most common bugs:

```
let bug init = 
   List.fold ~init ~f:(fun acc xs -> 
     List.fold ~init ~f:(fun acc x -> x :: acc))
```

Concerning the ugliness, I totally agree that underscores are ugly, but in most cases, this is the main purpose of them - to highlight the suspicious code. Concerning the example, that you're showing, in the modern OCaml it could be easily addressed with the inline records, e.g.,

```
type exp = 
  | Plus of {loc : loc; lhs : exp; rhs: exp}
  | ...
```

so that instead of using the underscores, you can just omit the unused field,

```
 let rec eval = function
   | Plus {lhs; rhs} -> eval lhs + eval rhs
```

You can use the same approach without using inline records by sparing some extra space in your program and defining all those records separately. The [real-world](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/ce4bd1e25fa0685f4db433c0ab6bc0a4ad86bdba/lib/bap_primus/bap_primus_lisp.ml#L346) example.

Comment: It's interesting how the nested fold example highlights that the labeled argument perhaps should have been called `acc` instead of `init`.

Comment: Great point too about the use of records instead of tuples. If only we had combined type definitions like `type t = Plus { loc : loc; lhs : t; rhs : t } | ...`

Comment: oh sh\*t I read your answer too fast, then realized that OCaml *already* has inline records. This made my day.

Comment: Your latter example triggers warning 9. Sure, it's not default, but it's not really a fix either.

Comment: @MartinJambon It's probably because they're so damn useful but I can't even remember coding without those. Have fun with them!

Comment: Well, there is a tradeoff always, warning 9 is disabled, and neither I would ever enable it. The reason? Warning 9 doesn't find bugs and has a very high level of false positives, while warning 27 finds bugs. So for me, it is a fix.

Comment: @ivg it won't find bugs firsthand, but having it activated can avoid a lot of problems when you later add a field to your record.

Comment: For those wondering, warning 9 is "Missing fields in a record pattern."

Answer (score 2):

For me this warning is useful in order to remind me to explicit more my intention. If we take your example :

```
fun (x, y) -> x;;
```

Your intention is to use only the first element. If we rewrite it this way :

```
fun (x, _ ) -> x;;
```

You use a pattern matching in the parameter to make your code more concise, but you explain your intention of using only the first element. The added value in this example is small, related to the very simple implementation. But in real life functions, this warning promote a good habit in coding.

Comment: I find this reduces code readability unless `_` really means "anything" or "anything else".

Comment: The issue is when there's a match case like `| Record (_, x, _, _) ->` and the  programmer needs to extend the code on the right-hand side. The underscores don't mean "anything"; they stand for values of specific types and specific roles, and hence could use a descriptive name.